# Mutable data pack into json

Tags: swift, swift3

How could I send hashed password with `sha256` via post request ?

```
 func sha256(string: String) -> Data? {
        guard let messageData = string.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8) else { return nil; }
        var digestData = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

        _ = digestData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {digestBytes in
            messageData.withUnsafeBytes {messageBytes in
                CC_SHA256(messageBytes, CC_LONG(messageData.count), digestBytes)
            }
        }
        return digestData
    }
```

This is how I am hasing a password.

Then whenever I try to pack it into an array as a `[String: Any]` it throws an exception in `JSONSErialization` `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Foundation._SwiftNSData)'`

```
 guard let loginURL = URL(string: LOGIN_URL) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }

        var loginURLRequest = URLRequest(url: loginURL)
        loginURLRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

        let content: [String: Any] = ["username": username, "passwordHash": password]
        let json: Data

        do {
            json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: content, options: [])
            loginURLRequest.httpBody = json
        } catch {
            print("Error: Can not create JSON")
            return
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How could i convert it ? Like this : `let tmp = password.base64EncodedString()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you *probably* want to do is encode the hash as a hex string.  Given your `sha256` function defined above, The following will do that:

```
let password = sha256(string: "myPassword")
    .map { return String(format: "%02x", $0) }
    .joined()

let content = [ 
    "username": username,
    "passwordHash": password
]
```

Alternatively, you could change your `sha256` function to return a string (and make it an extension of string):

```
func sha256() -> String? {
    guard let messageData = data(using:String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        return nil
    }

    var digestData = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    _ = digestData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { digestBytes in
        withUnsafeBytes { messageBytes in
            CC_SHA256(messageBytes, CC_LONG(messageData.count), digestBytes)
        }
    }

    return digestData.map { return String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
}
```

*Note:* I'm winging this a little since CommonCrypto won't work in a playground and I'm too lazy to wrap a whole project around this, but the important parts are here.

1. Use `data.map` to iterate over each byte in the hash
2. convert it to a hex string with `String(format: "%02x"...)`
3. put it all back together with `joined()`

Comment: Thanks ! Now i get it :) Could you explain yet how exactly that works : `%02x` ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html